# Lack of a close button on UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am currently doing some updates for an iOS application. For the update I am going to take advantage of iOS6 capabilities. I am using a UIActivityViewController to get this done as well as some custom UIActivity activities. The main issue I am having is that there is no "Cancel" or "Close" button. The only way you can exit out of the activity view is if you either post something to a social network, or act like you are going to and then cancel.

```
NSArray* dataToShare = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"blah", nil];
// Custom activities are allocated here
NSArray* customActivities = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:activities, nil];
NSArray* excludedActivities = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:exclusions, nil];

activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:formatArray applicationActivities:customActivities];
activityController.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities;

activityController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:self.view];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow bringSubviewToFront:activityController.view];
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:^{ closureCode
}];
```

This does everything that I need inside of the activity controller in terms of networking content, I just don't have a close button. I don't know if it is the same issue but when the view disappears if I try to bring one up my "Share" menu again it tells me

```
<UIActivityViewController: 0x1e0db7d0>  on <ShareDelegate: 0x1e048490> which is already presenting <UIActivityViewController: 0x21b1d4f0>
```

Thoughts? Thanks in advance!

*I am using:

- iPad 2
- Objective-C/C++
- XCode 4.5
- iOS6

Comment: Isn't already have a cancel button by default? http://www.techotopia.com/images/3/31/IPhone_iOS6_social_network_selection.png

Comment: Nah, I am on iPad. For some reason it would just come up with the activities but no cancel. On my iPhone it works with the code above and looks like the picture you showed (something close to it for me at least)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs for `UIActivityViewController` (emphasis is mine):

> When presenting the view controller, you must do so using the appropriate means for the current device. **On iPad, you must present the view controller in a popover.** On iPhone and iPod touch, you must present it modally.

On the iPad, the popover will be cancelled by the user tapping outside of the popover.

On the iPhone/iPod touch, the modal view controller will be shown with a cancel button.

In short, don't use a form sheet on the iPad.

Comment: This worked out fantastically. I probably should have caught that little tidbit but I somehow missed it. New to iOS programming and Objective-C so all the help I get I am definitely grateful for. Thanks!