# When and how to dismiss UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, uikit

I create and present `UIActivityViewController` in my app with custom `UIActivity` items in it.

When I tap `UIActivity` icon, `UIActivityViewController` slides down and my modal view controller is presented. However, when I dismiss my VC, `UIActivityViewController` shows up.

How can I make it disappear and never shows up again when activity item is pressed?

Comment: you read the accepted answer of this post..i think it really helps you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570753/lack-of-a-close-button-on-uiactivityviewcontroller

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the `activityDidFinish:` method on the chosen `UIActivity`.

From the docs for `UIActivity activityDidFinish:`:

> **Discussion**
> This method dismisses the sharing interface provided by the `UIActivityViewController` object. If you provided a view controller using the `activityViewController` method, this method dismisses that view controller too.
>
> You must call this method after completing the work associated with this object’s service. This is true regardless of whether you used the `activityViewController` or `performActivity` method to initiate the service. When calling the method, use the Boolean value to indicate whether the service completed successfully.

Comment: When should I call activityDidFinish? When I'm calling it when my VC is presented, VC is dismissed and after that, UIActivityVC slides down. Another issue: I don't want to let my VC know anything about who's presenting it. Ideally, there should be presentingViewControllerWillBeDismissed method in UIActivityVC so I could also dismiss UIActivityVC.

Comment: You do not dismiss your VC. When the user is done with the VC, you call `activityDidFinish:` on the activity. As stated in the docs I quoted, this will dismiss the VC and the activity view.

Comment: If you want complete control over when and how the VC is presented and dismissed, then call `activityDidFinish:` in your activity as soon as it is selected. Then present the VC yourself instead of returning it from the activity. Then, of course, you dismiss it when you appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say when Activity *A* is chosen from UIActivityVC, you want to present modal view controller *M* on your current view Controller *C* .

If you implement *A*'s `-(UIViewController*)activityViewController` method, you need to call `[A activityDidFinish]` in your modal view controller *M*'s dismiss method;

If you implement *A*'s `-(void) performActivity` method, it's impossible to present modal view , because current view controller *C* is in the process of dismissing `UIActivityVC` .

I think the final solution is a bit tricky. My basic idea is to subclass `UIActivityViewController` and override `-(void) viewDidDisappear` method. Thus you can do whatever you like( i.e present your own modal view,or push a sequence of other view controllers)  on your current view controller C.

Comment: i have a problem coming back from view controller  M, Attempt to present AddScreen:  on WBTabBarController: which is already presenting UIActivityViewController, is that because i don't dismiss the uiactivityVC ?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue as skovie. @skovie did you find any solution for this

Comment: I didn't read code, but i guess it's the same problem as trying to present modal view controller while current modal view controller is not dismissed, try present the 2nd modal view controller when 1st modal view controller's  `-(void) viewDidDisappear`

Answer (score 0):

i found this by Ethan Huang

```
        [self presentViewController: activityController animated: YES completion:nil];



        activityController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
        UIPopoverPresentationController *popPC = activityController.popoverPresentationController;
        popPC.barButtonItem = saveBtn;
        popPC.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
```

read all about it here :

http://getnotebox.com/developer/uiactivityviewcontroller-ios-8/